# Selecting 3.3v or 5v to supply EEPROM by µC output

Tags: pic, power, switches

I am looking to select the power supply voltage to an EEPROM depending on the output of a microcontroller.

Basically I am building a universal EEPROM (flash) programmer, and I need to select whether to power the EEPROM itself by 3.3v or 5v.

I was thinking of simply using a couple of transistors to select one of the two power lines, and I can easily switch one line on or off, but can't for the life of me work out how to switch the other line to the opposite.

I could possibly use an analog multiplexer to do it, but I think that's probably overkill, and I'm not sure if it could handle the current anyway.

The output of the µC is HCMOS at 3.3V.

A typical EEPROM pulls typically up to 45mA or so peak.

I want to avoid having the two voltage rails on at the same time, but I am happy to have neither on during the switching.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could start from a classic adjustable LDO application:

[image: LP3874 application]

I picked the [LP3874](http://www.national.com/ds/LP/LP3874-ADJ.pdf) because it has a **very low dropout** voltage of 24mV. By switching R2 between two values you can have 3.3V or 5V at the output, even with 5V in.

**Calculations**
If we pick 4700\$\Omega\$ for R1, then R2 must be 2700\$\Omega\$ for 3.3V out, and 1500\$\Omega\$ for 5V out. So for R2 place 1500\$\Omega\$ in series with 1200\$\Omega\$ and place a switch parallel to the 1200\$\Omega\$.

A BJT as switch is maybe not such a good idea, because of the \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$, but a small logic MOSFET is possible. Even a common [BSS138](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BS/BSS138W.pdf) (with an \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ of 6\$\Omega\$) is usable.

**edit**
Not everybody seems to be convinced of the BSS138, but its resistance actually brings the voltages closer to their theoretical value than 0\$\Omega\$: 0.22% instead of 0.52% for the 5V, and 0.85% instead of 1% for the 3.3V.
Also it only has a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ of 1.5V maximum for \$I_D\$ = 1mA, which is about what flows through the resistor divider.

Comment: You're the third to post that idea, but you suggested a part with an order of magnitude lower dropout which should probably satisfy the objection to doing it that way.

Comment: @Chris - I must admit that I didn't read the other answers in detail, but I realized that the ultra-low dropout was crucial to make it an attractive solution.

Comment: Dropout voltage is 35 mV max at 80 mA. Vdropout increases about linearly with current. That's about 0.44 ohm equivalent resistance. Using a MOSFET as a pass element a Vdropout of about 10 x smaller is easy enough (Rdson < 40 milliOhm).

Comment: BSS138 has too high Rdson and gate drive Voltage need are marginal or worse. About 1.5 Ohm Rdson at say 80 mA. Over 100 mV voltage drop. May or may not be bearable depending on other factors.

Comment: @Russell - I realize there are MOSFETs with lower \$R_{DS(ON)}\$, but 6\$\Omega\$ is only 0.4% of 1500\$\Omega\$, which is probably better than the resistor tolerances, and besides, in this case, with this resistance the required voltages are better approximated than with 0.0\$\Omega\$. \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ < 1.5V for a current of 1mA, which is the order of current through the divider. And OP needs only 45mA from the supply, so the 24mV is a justified estimate.

Comment: @Russell - about the dropout. You show me a 5V memory device which fails to work at 4.965V and I'll buy you a drink. Two if you want.

Comment: What I meant was that choosing a part that gets the voltage drop into an "unlikely to be an issue" range makes this the best of the adjust-an-adjustable-LDO ideas.  While better performance might be had with all discretes, I suspect most would be more comfortable with this solution, at least if the supply chain for the chosen part checks out.

Comment: Different voltages involved but the principle is the same. See [Signetics 25120 WOM](http://www.national.com/rap/files/datasheet.pdf) I understand that Olin is expert in these so can probably add valuable comment. Note that Vff is AC but not relevant to this issue. Mote that Vcc has no tolerance spec so must be precise for correct operation.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to achieve this.  The simplest I can think of is to use two microcontroller outputs, one to drive the EEPROM supply to 3.3V and the other to 5V.  Each would turn on a PNP high side switch transistor when low.  Just make sure you don't set both lines low simultaneously in the firmware.

### Added:

Now that we know you want to do this from one output, it gets more complicated.  You could switch one output with a single PNP, and the other with a NPN driving the PNP.  That way the on/off sense of the two will be inverted from each other.

The tricky part will be to a break before make when switching.  You should be able to arrange the switching levels so that there is a dead band in the middle when both power outputs are off.  However, the switch off times will likely be longer than the switch on times.  You can solve this with a little low pass filtering to limit the slew rate such that one output has time to switch off before the next hits the turn on threshold.  Yes, this is a bit of a kludge.

There are various other possible kludges, including digital I/O expansion, or a analog circuit that starts with the higher voltage and regulates down to 5V or 3.3V depending on the level of the control line.

All of these are rather a long way to go to avoid using a micro with more pins though.

Comment: Alas I don't have a 2nd output to use.  I have had to switch to an external clock module to release one output to allow me to do this switching as it is.

Comment: I'm already running with 40 pins (or 44 if I go TQFP).  The next step up is 64 pins, which is very much overkill, plus would require quite a large recode of the system.

Comment: And as for the break-before-make - it's not strictly necessary - it would be nice, but not 100% needed.  All the EEPROMs I will be using can tolerate 5v for a short time (we're talking minutes, even hours), but I'd rather avoid that spike.  My main concern is the 5v feeding back down the 3.3v line to damage one of the other 3.3v only components elsewhere.

Comment: @Matt if you are concerned about a 3.3v part over-voltaged to 5v putting a damaging voltage on a shared bus, perhaps you should be concerned about a 5v part doing that too, and use current limiting resistors and possibly even discrete clamp diodes on the bus if the other 3.3v components do not have 5v tolerant IOs.

Comment: @Chris There is only one part that is not 5V tolerant, and that's the clock generator.  Everything else can run at between 2.8v and 5.5v.  The only part that will be running at 5v (sometimes) is directly connected to one and only one component which has fully 5v tolerant inputs.  I don't want the clock generator to get a blast of 5V though and go pop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method - number 4 - added at start.

**4 . Another scintillating diagram.**

When Vc is high

- IC1 ref is grounded.
- IC1 never on.
- so Q1 never on.
- so Q2 always on via R3 gate drive.
- so 5v fed to output.

When Vc is low

- Q3 (lower right not namjed) is off so
- IC1 ref is driven by R4/R5 divider. IC1 ref  = 2V5 when Vout = 3V3 with values for r4 R5 as shown.
- IC1 turning on when Vout risese to 3V3 turns on Q1
- Q1 on turns off Q2.
- Output regulates at 3V3 or whatever voltage desired.

If desired two voltages both < 5V could b provided this way by switching IC1 gate divider as required.

Components: 1 P channel MOSFET - could be PNP transistor, 2 x jellybean bipolar transistors, 6 x R, TL431 adjustable clamp regulator (very low cost).

Note - such circuits may tend to oscillate. Some capacitance at one of several nodes will stop this. More details if desired.

[image]

[TL431 shunt regulator data sheet](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/TL431_432.pdf)
31 cents in 1's at Digikey. Under 10 cents in 1000's fwiw.

---

Summary: **Method 3 below is cheap easy and effective, choose any 3.**

(1) You could use a regulator whose output voltage can be switched from 3V3 to 5V. eg an LM317 with a resistor divider to set voltage and a transistor switch to short out part of the divider.

(2) As current drain is probably low you could feed the supply through a resistor with a suitable reservoir  capacitor and then have a clamp regulator switched in (eg TL431 etc) when you want 3V3. (I like the first option better).

(3) **Best?:** It only takes a few transistors to arrange a switch which switches on transistor Qhi5 when the input is high and Qhi3v3 when the input is low. I'll draw you a circuit later if wanted. [Quck back of, literally, envelope - 2 power switch transistors and two jellybean input transistors. Qin1 switches Qhi5 on when input is high. When input is low Qin1 collector (or drain) goes high, Qhi5 is off but this switches on Qin2 which switches on Qhi3 on. 4 transistors, probably 6 resistors. A little care with crossover but not hard. Circuit provided if wanted. If 2 pins were available you could eliminate Qin1 and Qin2.

Here's one way - super rough - rushing ...

I've shown P Channel FETS for Qhi5 and Qhi3v3 but these could be PNP transistors. A little more care may be needed at changeover, maybe not. Resistor drive to Qin2 has to be dimensuoned so as to not turn on Qhi5V when Qin1 is off. Just a matter of design (as ever :-) ). More later  if wanted ... .  Rushing ... .

[image]

Comment: LM317 is out - the drop-out is way too high.  I am running from a 4.5 to 5v supply (USB) through an LDO regulator for the 3.3v.  I like the transistor solution the best, if you could give me a more pictorial view of it.

Comment: The format of the LM317 idea probably would work tolerably if an adjustable LDO was used instead.

Comment: @Chris It would have to be a regulator of 0 dropout for a 5v input to give a 5v output.

Comment: @Matt Yes, to get 5v output it would.  But you might get a high-enough output.  Essentially, I found the idea interesting again when I realized that it would yield a higher output voltage in "5v"mode than the shunt regulator idea.  You can see what kind of voltage drop you get with PFETs.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if a tiny SPDT relay might not be a better idea.

Comment: A relays does allow simplicity :-). Could also use 2 x SPST eg reeds - better in some cases.  // BUT My circuit is extremely simple in practice. Would need a little playing but about OK as is **EXCEPT** use PNP transistor at least for Qhi3V3 as otherwise the reverse body diode will backfeed  5V to 3V3 when 5V is on. A small amount of design thought will get a workable supply with about the same complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I have some reservations about this idea so I am more tossing it out for discussion than suggesting you do it this way:

In the really old days before 3-terminal regulators, people used to make voltage regulators with a series resistor and a zener diode to ground.  This was wasteful, but I doubt your EEPROM draws much current, so it might be reasonable.

The trick would be to put a transistor in series with the zener, and adjust the zener voltage accordingly.  As a safety measure, you could pull up the base of the transistor so it would be on, ie, in 3.3v mode, until the micro specifically grounded the base to remove the zener and allow the output to rise up to VBus.

You could also check the data sheet and make sure the 5v part won't work at 3.3v.

And for that matter, you could see what happens if you take a 3.3v regulator and put a transistor in series with its ground lead.

**EDIT: Better idea:**

The shunt regulator will end up dropping close to half a volt across its resistor when supplying 45ma in "5v" mode (and consuming about 1/4 of the USB current allowance in 3.3v mode).  But a small LDO such as the LT1761 has a dropout voltage of less than that at 50 ma load (and acccording to LT, "in dropout, output voltage will be equal to: VIN – VDROPOUT").  So buy the adjustable version and use it with a transistor in the reference divider as Russel suggested for the higher dropout LM317.

Comment: The zener concept is what I described in my shunt regulator suggestion - but the shunt regulator can be very precise (eg TL431 available in 0.5 / 1 / 2% versions)

Comment: @Russel - good point.  Though running the numbers it seems marginal with either shunt - ie, 11 ohm series resistor would drop half a volt at 45 ma, but consume 155 ma or burn 1/4 watt when shunted down to 3.3v.  It probably would work, but I'm not entirely comfortable with the droop or dissipation - and to be USB compliant it would have to be in 5v ie low current mode until negotiation for full current is complete, though it seems nobody abides by that.

Comment: "You could also check the data sheet and make sure the 5v part won't work at 3.3v." The part in question is interchangeable in a ZIF socket, so I cannot guarantee that a 5v part will run at 3.3v.